# Find architecture of system in Windows Installer

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have a application developed in C#. I am creating an installer for the app using Visual Studio Setup Project.

While installation, I want to execute an exe file which differs for 32 and 64 bit respectively. So I have to use different file for 32bit and 64bit.

For executing exe file, I have added "Custom Action" and that works also. But as said, the exe file differs for system architectire. How can I knwo the architecture in installer and execute the respective file.

**I tried the following :**
Check the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node - If found then also it returns "" and else also returns "", so of no use.
VersionNT - that provides only version, I am more concerned with Architecture.

How can I achieve this ? VBS can do the work or not ? I don't know vbs, but know that it can be added to action and set its condition and little bit things like that.

If at all I create another 32bit app that detects the architecture, then also how would that work out with this suring installation ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at second comment here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724072%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Today I got an idea: you may also check existance of "Program Files (x86)" directory or corresponding env variable.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the property **[VersionNT64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372497%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)** which is only set on 64-bit systems. If you need to differentiate between IA64 and x64, see also properties **[Intel64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369553%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)** and **[Msix64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

For example you may use a condition on your component or custom action that reads **VersionNT64** if you want it to install or run on only 64-bit systems.